# Retrofit: deserialization with jackson fails without any error

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, retrofit

I have the following code that I use to call a Rest-API: service

```
Retrofit client = Client.getClient();
Call<ResponseBeanOutput<UserBeanOutput>> call = client.create(AuthResource.class).login("username","password","true");
Response<ResponseBeanOutput<UserBeanOutput>> response = call.execute();
```

The client is obteined via a static method:

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(getBaseUrl())
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(mapper))
            .build();
}
```

Server sends a response in JSON like this:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "Successfull login",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "data": {
        "uid": 7,
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "name": "username",
        "nick": "usernick",
        "photoUrl": "media/profiles/defaultImageProfile.png",
        "lts": "aaaaeqc9lf9od82rk633aaaaa"
    }
}
```

I have to map this response into a generic object ResponseBeanOutput that contains a field (data) of type UserBeanOutput (mapping the object "data" in json object). So in the end ResponseBeanOutput will map fields "error","message","errorCode" and data will be an object of type "UserBeanOutput" containing "uid","email","nick", etc.

My problem is that all objects are empty (null) and I have no errors.

I tried also to remove generic type from ResponseBeanOutput and to map a response with a simple bean with fields "error" and "message" with releted getter and setter but without any success.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to debug Retrofit? It works for me in most cases, when I can't understand why 3-rd party libraries don't work as I expect. Just put a breakpoint at the start of .execute() method and step by step you will find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue following suggestion of @Yevhenii Semenov, debugging execute() method. I found that the problem was in the API that didn't return body in the response and for this reason the deserialization was null.
The code for initialize the client was fine.

Thanks